# Quick way to find all permutations of a pandas DataFrame that preserves a sort?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, permutation

I have a DataFrame, and I'd like find all the permutations of it that fulfill a simple ascending sort on one of the columns. (There are many ties.) For example, in the following DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["Abe", "Bob", "Chris", "David", "Evan"], 
                   'age': [28, 20, 21, 22, 21]})
```

I'd be looking to sort by age and obtain the orders `["Bob", "Chris", "Evan", "David", "Abe"]` and `["Bob", "Evan", "Chris", "David", "Abe"]`.

I'm new to python (and to pandas) and curious if there is a simple way to do this that I don't see.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the second combination be `['Bob', 'Evan', 'Chris', 'David', 'Abe']`?

Comment: Yes; whoops! Edited. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: `groupby` by age, multiply the permutations of each age-group?

Comment: `df.sort(['age', 'name'], ascending=[1, 0])` and `df.sort(['age', 'name'], ascending=[1, 1])` should give you both the orders you mentioned, does that work for you?

Comment: This would give both orders for the example, yes. But, I don't think it would scale easily to the case of my actual DataFrame, which has more than one tie (e.g., two 22 year-olds, but also two 30 year-olds), as well as sometimes more than 2 items tied (e.g., three 22 year-olds).

Comment: Yes. Then you could add all the columns on which you to sort the age on and then permute on [0, 1] pairs in `ascending=`?

Comment: If you have three 21-year-olds, the two sorts you mention don't cover it, @JohnGalt. You have to have all six permutations of the three 21-year-olds, times the (say) 24 permutations of four 18-year-olds, etc.

Comment: @cphlewis Ah, it's clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're grouping by age, let's do that and return all the permutations for each group and then take the product (using itertools' product and permutation functions):

```
In [11]: age = df.groupby("age")
```

If we look at the permutations of a single group:

```
In [12]: age.get_group(21)
Out[12]:
   age   name
2   21  Chris
4   21   Evan

In [13]: list(permutations(age.get_group(21).index))
Out[13]: [(2, 4), (4, 2)]

In [14]: [df.loc[list(p)] for p in permutations(age.get_group(21).index)]
Out[14]:
[   age   name
 2   21  Chris
 4   21   Evan,    age   name
 4   21   Evan
 2   21  Chris]
```

We can do this on the entire DataFrame by returning just the index for each group (this assumes that the index is unique, if it's not `reset_index` prior to doing this... you *may* be able to do something slightly more lower level):

```
In [21]: [list(permutations(grp.index)) for (name, grp) in age]
Out[21]: [[(1,)], [(2, 4), (4, 2)], [(3,)], [(0,)]]

In [22]: list(product(*[(permutations(grp.index)) for (name, grp) in age]))
Out[22]: [((1,), (2, 4), (3,), (0,)), ((1,), (4, 2), (3,), (0,))]
```

We can glue these up with sum:

```
In [23]: [sum(tups, ()) for tups in product(*[(permutations(grp.index)) for (name, grp) in age])]
Out[23]: [(1, 2, 4, 3, 0), (1, 4, 2, 3, 0)]
```

If you make these a list you can apply loc (which gets you the desired result):

```
In [24]: [df.loc[list(sum(tups, ()))] for tups in product(*[list(permutations(grp.index)) for (name, grp) in age])]
Out[24]:
[   age   name
 1   20    Bob
 2   21  Chris
 4   21   Evan
 3   22  David
 0   28    Abe,    age   name
 1   20    Bob
 4   21   Evan
 2   21  Chris
 3   22  David
 0   28    Abe]
```

And the (list of) the name column:

```
In [25]: [list(df.loc[list(sum(tups, ())), "name"]) for tups in product(*[(permutations(grp.index)) for (name, grp) in age])]
Out[25]:
[['Bob', 'Chris', 'Evan', 'David', 'Abe'],
 ['Bob', 'Evan', 'Chris', 'David', 'Abe']]
```

---

Note: It *may* be faster to use a [numpy permutation matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27323448/1240268) and `pd.tools.util.cartesian_product`. I suspect it's much of a muchness and wouldn't explore this unless this was unusably slow (it's potentially going to be slow anyway because there could be many many permutations)...

Answer (score 1):

Halfway:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations, product

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["Abe", "Bob", "Chris", "David",
                            "Evan","Ford","Giles","Ham"],
                   'age': [20, 20, 21, 22,
                           21, 21, 22, 22]})

dfg = df.groupby('age')
perms = {}
for k, v in dfg:
    perms[k] =  list(permutations(v.values))

print(perms)
```

and the product of the right view of the values of `perms` is Bob-your-21-year-old-uncle.

Comment: Bob is 20!! :) It's not clear to me what you want to do with this result. It's a dict of lists of tuples of numpy arrays (which has the age and name)! :(

Answer (score 0):

Following cphlewis, I ended up with:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["Abe", "Bob", "Chris", "David",
                            "Evan", "Ford", "Giles", "Ham"],
                   'age': [20, 21, 20, 20,
                           24, 25, 25, 27]})

dfg = df.groupby('age')

permsAtEachAge = []
for age, people in dfg:
    permsAtEachAge.append(list(it.permutations(people.name.values)))

product = list(it.product(*permsAtEachAge))
overallPermutations = map(lambda x: list(it.chain(*x)), product)
```

Andy Hayden's complete solution looks to work perfectly, as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can use numpy to sort like

> np.sort(data[age])[::-1]

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd

df.sort_values(by = 'age')
```