# Finding number of occurrences of each row in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Given an entirely categorical data frame like so

```
 import pandas as pd

 data = {"Name": ["Dakota", "Joe", "Dakota", "Alex", "Dakota"],
         "Activities":["Chess", "Bowling", "Chess", "Swimming", "Chess"],
         "Gender": ["Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female"]}

 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I would like to count how many times each row occurs something like

```
 Dakota Chess Male: 2
 Dakota Chess Female: 1
 Joe Bowling Male: 1
 Alex Female Swimming: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.groupby(by = ['Name','Activities','Gender'])['Gender'].count()

Name    Activities  Gender

Alex    Swimming    Female    1

Dakota  Chess       Female    1
                    Male      2

Joe     Bowling     Male      1

Answer (score 1):

I think you need all permutations using data from existing dataframe. Check answers here: [Quick way to find all permutations of a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992105/quick-way-to-find-all-permutations-of-a-pandas-dataframe-that-preserves-a-sort)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert all rows to a list of lists and then use Counter from collections.

```
allValues=df.values.tolist()

rows = []

for row in allValues:
    rows.append(' '.join(row))



print(Counter(rows))
```

Output:
Counter({'Dakota Chess Male': 2, 'Joe Bowling Male': 1, 'Alex Swimming Female': 1, 'Dakota Chess Female': 1})