# Get all permutations of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, ...] which only contains the numbers 0-k. I would like to create a new array that contains the n possible arrays of permutations of 0-k. A small example with k=2 and n=6:

```
a = [0, 1, 0, 2]
permute(a)
result = [[0, 1, 0, 2]
          [0, 2, 0, 1]
          [1, 0, 1, 2]
          [2, 1, 2, 0]
          [1, 2, 1, 0]
          [2, 0, 2, 1]]
```

Does anyone have any ideas/solutions as to how one could achieve this?

Comment: This is a duplicate plus a [google away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323448/numpy-array-to-permutation-matrix).

Comment: @kabanus OP seems to want *distinguishable* permutations -- which that link doesn't give.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your **a** is what combinatorists call a *multiset*. The **[sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/)** library has [various routines](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/combinatorics/permutations.html) for working with them.

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2])
>>> for p in multiset_permutations(a):
...     p
...     
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: did not know about this one. learned something new! thanks! +1

Comment: Which is a big reason for my presence here too!

Answer (score 36):

if your permutations fit in the memory, you could store them in a `set` and thus only get the distinguishable permutations.

```
from itertools import permutations

a = [0, 1, 0, 2]

perms = set(permutations(a))
```

Comment: This is probably okay for small examples, but this involves generating n! permutations when the number of distinguishable permutations might be much smaller

Comment: @JohnColeman: i agree. but as i have no idea how big the sample is... it might just work.

Comment: As is often the case in Python, it is a question of scale. This is a perfectly good approach for smaller examples (which is why I upvoted it). For larger examples you would want to use a library with multiset support (as the other answer has).

Comment: By the way -- `set(permutations(a))` is a 1-line implementation of your idea.