# How to get (k - 1)-combinations of numpy.arange(k)

Tags: numpy, range, combinations, numpy-ndarray

Given an `np.arange(k)` for any integer `k` value, I'm trying to find all its `(k - 1)`-combinations.

Example with `k = 4` (ideally by this order):

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Using regular python, this works:

```
[[j for j in range(k) if i != j] for i in range(k)]
```

But I was aiming for a more *numpythonic* approach. This is my best shot so far:

```
np.rot90(np.arange(k).repeat(k - 1).reshape((k - 1, k)))
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing it using numpy, or should I just use normal python?

Comment: `itertools` has a nice combinations function.

Comment: Have you tried to time the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

hpaulj already pointed it out in his comment, but here is one way of approaching this using [itertools combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np


k = 4
a = np.array([*combinations(np.arange(k), 3)])
print(a)
```

Maybe you also want to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41210450/5472354) which uses the [sympy library](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/combinatorics/permutations.html) to achieve similar stuff.